# Is there a way to get a list of databases and their codes using the quandl.com API?

Tags: quandl

I am currently working on a database that is using Quandl.com data. I have been reading the documentation of their API, which seems to have everything that I need, except for a list of Database codes.[Quandl API Docs](https://www.quandl.com/docs/api)

```
"https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/databases/WIKI.csv?api_key=YOURAPIKEY"
```

This link will load database meta-data (Wiki.csv), but you have to have the database name in order to use this. I am trying to figure out How to get a list of these databases with their codes. I have not found anything yet, unless I missed it. It seems odd not to be able to get a list of databases.

Is there a way to use this code to load database meta-data with out the name of the database and acquire a comprehensive list?

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve a list of all databases, use the following structure:

```
https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/databases?api_key=YOURAPIKEY
```

Traverse through the paged results by adding a 'page' query parameter:

```
https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/databases?api_key=YOURAPIKEY&page=2
```